# How to change colors in a picture on photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

[image]

Looking to change the white table cloth to a navy one, and the brown runner in the middle to white...  how to achieve this? thanks!! `

Comment: There are tons of tutorials (here and on the wide wild internet) so please use your search engine of preference (or the search box on the top right of the site)

Comment: Please show us what you have tried and why you aren't content with the results. As-is, your question is rather broad and therefore not a very good fit for our Q&A format.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're going to need to get yours hands dirty on this one - because of the similarity in colour between the tablecloth and the runner (not to mention that the background is white), the auto adjustments available to you (Image > adjustments) won't help. Personally, I'd carefully mask the left and right areas of tablecloth and the runner area separately (using the pen tool), create new fill layers, and use the layers' blend modes to colourise the image. It won't look perfect (as in reality the colours would reflect light differently to the source) but it's a start.

Here's the result of 2 minutes' work...

[image: recoloured table]